# How to set Swagger UI options when using @nestjs/swagger (ex: displayOperationId=true)

Tags: swagger, config, nestjs, swagger-ui

I can enable displaying the opperationId for each endpoint by putting the config in the url:
`http://localhost:3000/api?displayOperationId=true`

However, I want to have this as the default behavior. How do I set config variables for swagger-ui during the setup of the nestjs `SwaggerModule`

[image: See image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

The solution is based on your HTTP adapter, but the creation is the same:

**Creation:**

```js
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('title')
    .setDescription('desc')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .build();

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
```

**For Express:**

If you’re using Express (which is the default adapter) as your adapter

You need to pass `displayOperationId: true` In the [`swaggerOptions`](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/5596178934da1a13823e9488b3c97f0d0b5b2ade/lib/interfaces/swagger-custom-options.interface.ts#L3)

Like this:

```js
SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document, {
    swaggerOptions: {
      displayOperationId: true,
    },
});
```

**For Fastify:**

If you’re using Fastify as your adapter

You need to pass `displayOperationId: true` In the [`uiConfig`](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/5596178934da1a13823e9488b3c97f0d0b5b2ade/lib/interfaces/swagger-custom-options.interface.ts#L16)

Like this:

```js
SwaggerModule.setup('/docs', app, document, {
  uiConfig:  {
    displayOperationId: true,
  }
});
```